# Compiler errors when installing psycopg2 on OS X Yosemite

Tags: gcc, psycopg2

Command line tools are up to date, all other requirements are satisfied. I suspect this is some kind of compiler conflict, but I'm not certain. I'm not using a virtualenv.

```
pip install psycopg2
```

yields

```
gcc: error: x86_64: No such file or directory

gcc: error: unrecognized option '-arch'

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

The command is:

```
gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -I/Users/username/anaconda/include -arch x86_64 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.5.4 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090305 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/Users/username/anaconda/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.5_1/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.5_1/include/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o
```

Sidebar: I'm not certain why it's attempting to invoke anaconda, which I used to install Julia.

Answer (score 1):

This was resolved by removing the root directory for anaconda (with the `conda info` command). I'm still not clear on exactly why Anaconda produced those issues (would welcome information on this!), but at any rate the problem is fixed.